# How to connect PostgreSQL and PHP on mac?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am new to PHP. I want to use the database stored in pgSQL from my PHP file. Please tell how to integrate pgSQL and PHP, so that I can use pgSQL in PHP using `pg_connect()`. My `php.info()` is showing MySQL, pgSQL, SQLite enabled under PDO support. But when I use `pg_connect()` it says:

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist in /Users/username/Sites/index.php on line 3

Warning: pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet in /Users/username/Sites/index.php on line 4

Warning: pg_last_error(): supplied resource is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource in /Users/username/Sites/index.php on line 4
Could not connect:
```

I have used this tutorial to run PHP on Mac. But I couldn't find a tutorial clearly showing how to integrate PHP and pgSQL.

https://www.dyclassroom.com/howto-mac/how-to-install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14

```
<?php
  // Connecting, selecting database
  $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=ipl user=postgres password=password")
      or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

  // Performing SQL query
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM player';
  $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

  // Printing results in HTML
  echo "<table>\n";
  while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo "\t<tr>\n";
      foreach ($line as $col_value) {
          echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
      echo "\t</tr>\n";
  }
  echo "</table>\n";

  // Free resultset
  pg_free_result($result);

  // Closing connection
  pg_close($dbconn);
  ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, good question

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. My username is not postgres but my name. I must have set it while installing Postgres. Therefore it is saying no role as 'postgres' exist.